# python3.8 fails with "Fatal Python error: config_get_locale_encoding"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macports

OK, so somehow I have mangled my python3 installation under macOS Mojave and I'm not sure how. I've used macports for years to keep python up to date but when I installed python38 now I cannot run python3 at all. I always get this:

```
$ python3.8
Fatal Python error: config_get_locale_encoding: failed to get the locale encoding: nl_langinfo(CODESET) failed
Python runtime state: preinitialized
$
```

I uninstalled the macports version and reinstalled, same thing.  Uninstalled and then installed fresh from python.org, same thing.

python27 runs fine.  python37 also runs fine.  python38 won't even work if I use `$python3.8 -I` so it's not some site package weirdness.

Here's the really weird bit:  while I cannot run python38 from a shell (any shell, tried from bash , I can launch python38 from the GUI using IDLE.app.

Oddly, on my other machine (my laptop), python38 installed with macports works just fine.

I'm flummoxed and I don't flummox easily. Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try setting LANG with a locale:

```sh
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Sorry. Was in grading purgatory last week, and then I also spent time figuring out WHY the LANG variable wasn't being set. Problem with Terminal.app on one machine and not the other. Ugh.

Comment: did not help me, so this must not be the full answer

Comment: in case this fails, the following worked for me `export LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and fixed it by putting the following variable definition in my ~/.profile:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

LC_CTYPE was originally set to "De_DE" and was missing the encoding.

You should choose your language and country and set the value accordingly, e.g. this value for German/Germany:

```
export LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be another not obvious problem. If you put `export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"` in `~/.profile` file, check if there's no `~/.bash_profile` in the system. If `~/.bash_profile` exists commands in `~/.profile` will not be executed.